# Sql Server 2008 Reporting Fill Blanks with 0's

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi I have a table that has many blank values in it.  I would like to set these to show up as 0 .  Is there a way I can do this?  Preferably outside of the query, and within reporting services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can replace fields in the SSRS report that may contain blank values with expressions, for example:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!Username.Value), 0, Fields!Username.Value)
```